# Finding area of DEM raster clip?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dem

I have a DEM layer in ArcMap 10.2 which I then clipped to fit a large shapefile. I'm trying to find the area of the new DEM shape using the Image Analysis tools, specifically the Mensuration tools. I keep getting an error message "Not all points are in the current image". I haven't used these tools before and I'm relatively new at working with DEMs. Is there a better tool to use or a different process for measuring DEM files?

Comment: It's equal to the area of clipping geometry

Comment: @FelixIP would you mind expanding on that? I've just started recently working with DEM/rasters and still finding my way about it. where can i find the area of clipping geometry?

Comment: If you clipped it by polygon using ClippingGeometry, create field double in polygon table, right click, pick calculate geometry (area) on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Surface Volume tool (3D Analyst Tools) to get the footprint area, the surface area, and the volume.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, thank you! quick follow up Q: how do i tell the units of the DEM layer? it is currently listed as not having linear units, the data frame is in US feet, but the number I am getting for surface area is too small to be in SF. I feel like this is GIS 101 basic stuff but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: In ArcGIS  add the DEM to an ArcMap project, then right click the DEM and open the layer properties.  In the properties you will see the cell size but you will need to examine the spatial reference information to see the units of measure for those cells.  Keep in mind that the z values of the cells may be in a different unit of measure than the xy values.  The surface volume tool will let you add a scalar to make adjustments if this is the case...

Comment: It's possible to calculate surface volume tool in Raster Calculator?